# Error checkin Python-Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my ***route*** function :

```
@app.route('/home/shelter/<int:shelter_id>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def showShelterDetails(shelter_id):
    shelter = session.query(Shelter).filter_by(id = shelter_id).one()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['shelterName']:
            shelter.name = request.form['shelterName']
            session.add(shelter)
            session.commit()
            flash("Shelter("+shelter.name+") edited successfully!")
            return render_template('shelterdetails.html', shelter_id=shelter_id, shelter=shelter)
        else:
            flash(u'Error Occured!','error')
            return render_template('shelterdetails.html', shelter_id=shelter_id, shelter=shelter)

        if request.form['shelterAddress']:
            shelter.name = request.form['shelterAddress']
            session.add(shelter)
            session.commit()
            flash("Shelter("+shelter.name+") address edited successfully!")
            return render_template('shelterdetails.html', shelter_id=shelter_id, shelter=shelter)
        else:
            flash(u'Error Occured!','error')
            return render_template('shelterdetails.html', shelter_id=shelter_id, shelter=shelter)
    else:
        return render_template('shelterdetails.html', shelter_id = shelter_id, shelter = shelter)
```

Here is my ***HTML template*** :

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["message"]) %}
    {% if messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <strong>{{message}}!</strong>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

{% with errors = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["error"]) %}
  {% if errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      {% for message in errors %}
      <strong>{{message}}!</strong>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
<form action="{{ url_for('showShelterDetails',shelter_id=shelter_id )}}" method = 'post'>

  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="shelterName">Name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:500px" name="shelterName" value='{{ shelter.name }}' >
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="shelterName">Address :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:500px" name="shelterAddress" value='{{ shelter.address }}'>
  </fieldset>
```

---

My problem is : The POST method doesn't check whether the `shelterAddress` field is empty or blank or not. Also while returning the success or failure messages. Only the top 1 message gets printed.

Why do the other messages not get printed ? Also why doesn't it check for empty fieds ?

---

**EDIT 1:**
Changed my view function to :

```
@app.route('/home/shelter/<int:shelter_id>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def showShelterDetails(shelter_id):
    shelter = session.query(Shelter).filter_by(id = shelter_id).one()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['shelterName']!="":
            shelter.name = request.form['shelterName']
            session.add(shelter)
            session.commit()
            flash("Shelter("+shelter.name+") edited successfully!")

        if request.form['shelterAddress']!= "":
            shelter.name = request.form['shelterAddress']
            session.add(shelter)
            session.commit()
            flash("Shelter("+shelter.name+") address edited successfully!")

    else:
        return render_template('shelterdetails.html', shelter_id = shelter_id, shelter = shelter)
```

> ValueError: View function did not return a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're returning early whether `request.form['shelterName']` is truthy or not. You probably want one return statement at the very end of your view function instead.

Comment: Can you explain it through an example ?

Comment: Please look at the edited question. I get an ValueError

Comment: How did I print one success message for all valid data and all error messages for invalid inputs ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Follow the if-else logic. At what point do you return a value? If `request.method` is `POST`, do you return a value?

Comment: No worries. I solved it using multiple `and` conditions!